# How to add an image to Excel using XSLT

Tags: excel, image, xslt

Hello and thanks in advance!

I'm trying to implement an image to an excel file generated with xslt.
The image is in the root of the Application, so it has nothing to do with the XML im parsing.

```
   <worksheet ss:Name="RELATÓRIO">
      <Table>
        <ss:Column ss:Width="150"/>
        <Row ss:Index="1">
          <Cell ss:Index="1">
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <img src="info_img_teste.png" align="left"/>
              HELLO
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
      </Table>
    </worksheet>
```

This is what I have but it doesn't work, anyone has any idea how to implement this?

Comment: The way to find out what the XML should be like is to open up Excel, insert an image into a cell, and save the spreadsheet in "Xml Spreadsheet 2003" format. Then edit the file in a text editor, and see what the XML is like.

Comment: Ok im sorry i think i've explained myself wrongly!
The image i have to implement in the Worksheet is the Logo of my company, And this must be present in all of the Excel files, that are Automaticaly generated Reports Created with XSLT , So basicly i just need to Use the image i already have , and just show it in the Excel file, but this has to be done Via XSLT , Thanks in advance!

Comment: He explained to you how to find out for yourself how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

The Excel 2003 XML format does not support embedded images - the full list of what is and is not retained/supported when using the Excel 2003 file format is here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-lost-when-i-save-my-workbook-as-an-xml-spreadsheet-2003-file-8e7e858b-eda6-47eb-a1e5-b82a7bdffc3f

Listed specifically as "Not retained":

> Charts, PivotCharts, and other graphic objects

As an alternative, depending on the required functionality in the file you're creating, the Word 2003 XML format *does* support embedded images via Base64-encoded strings. If that's preferred, you could then embed a table in a Word document along with your desired image.